# Wordpress add_action for save_post problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on throwing custom fields to a post in my plugin when it's saved.

I ran into a problem today. Even if the post is not saved, the function is called when entering the edit screen.

Moreover, multiple cuts are working. (all posts)

This may be the reason, below is the code sample I used in my plugin.

```php
<?php
add_action('save_post', 'my_plugin_function', 10, 2);

function my_plugin_function($post_id)
{
    ....
}
?>
```

I wanted this code to run only when a new post is added or any post is edited.

For the relevant post only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below the

```
 function my_plugin_function($ID, $post,$update) {

   if($update == false) {
     // do something if its first time publish
   } else {
     // Do something if its update
   }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_function', 10, 3 );
```